# Sync between Google calendar and Calendar.app stopped working

Tags: calendar, google-calendar, google-sync

A few days ago the sync between google calendar and calendar app stopped working for me - the app can't retrieve new events/calendars and if I create events in it - they won't appear in GCal. I've tried re-adding google account, removing google related keychains. That did not help.
I'd appreciate your advice on this one.

The app version is 9.0 (2155.21)

Comment: Which application are you using to make this synchronization?
Which application is at version 9.0?

Comment: Standard Calendar.app, as mentioned in the question header